# Swift - Cannot get element of NSMutableArray()

Tags: swift, position, nsmutablearray, element

Let me start off with my code before i explain everything.

**CardInfo_Adapter.swift**

```
class CardInfo_Adapter: AnyObject {        
    var CardName: String = String()
    var NoResults: String = String()
}
```

Okay, so what i'm trying to do is get the the position of an element of a returned NSMutableArray() that accesses my database for a list of card names.

I'm trying to check if the results came back empty or not.

Here is the code i'm using first to do that.

```
returnedCardNames = NSMutableArray()
returnedCardNames = Card_Adapter.getInstance().getAllSimilarCardNamesByUserEntry("rthrthrth", passedSeriesName: "null", passedSetName: "null")

    if returnedCardNames.objectAtIndex(0) as! String == "No results found."
```

Now, the error i'm getting is this

```
Could not cast value of type 'AppName.CardInfo_Adapter' (0x10ce1c370) to 'NSString
```

What i don't get is that **returnedCardNames** is a NSMutableArray(), why is it thinking it's of type **CardInfo_Adapter**?

There is absolutely nothing in my swift file that contains the if statement, that uses the CardInfo_Adapter.swift

UPDATE: Here is the code in **getAllSimilarCardNamesByUserEntry**. I get that i use **CardInfo_Adapter** in this part but shouldn't it still be an object inside the NSMutableArray(), since that's what type of function and return value i use.

```
func getAllSimilarCardNamesByUserEntry(passedCardName: String, passedSeriesName: String, passedSetName: String) -> NSMutableArray {

    let returnedSimilarNames : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var returnedCardSet = String()

    let NoResults : CardInfo_Adapter = CardInfo_Adapter()
    NoResults.CardName = "No results found."
    print("No results found.")
    returnedSimilarNames.addObject(NoResults)
    returnedSimilarNames.removeAllObjects()
    returnedSimilarNames.addObject(NoResults)

    return returnedSimilarNames
}
```

Comment: What's your code for `getAllSimilarCardNamesByUserEntry`?

Comment: Added the bare part of the code of what i'm trying to check. I use this exact code when i actually do get search results and i can successfully load a TableView with the data. I just don't know why i can't use an IF Statement and look for a specific string.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do but you can define `arrays` like `your_name:[your_type]=[]` and `Strings` like `your_name:String!`. You don't need to use `NSMutableArray` in `swift`.

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        var returnedCardNames:[CardInfo_Adapter] = []

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            var returnedCardNames = getAllSimilarCardNamesByUserEntry("rthrthrth", passedSeriesName: "null", passedSetName: "null")
            let item = returnedCardNames[0]


            if item.NoResults == "No results found." {
                // do stuff
            } else {
                // do stuff
            }
        }

        func getAllSimilarCardNamesByUserEntry(passedCardName: String, passedSeriesName: String, passedSetName: String) -> [CardInfo_Adapter] {
            var returnedSimilarNames:[CardInfo_Adapter] = []

            // you are not using this here.
            //var returnedCardSet:String!

            let NoResults = CardInfo_Adapter()
            NoResults.CardName = "No results found."
            print("No results found.")
            returnedSimilarNames.append(NoResults)
            returnedSimilarNames.removeAll()
            returnedSimilarNames.append(NoResults)

            return returnedSimilarNames
        }
    }

    class CardInfo_Adapter {
        var CardName:String!
        var NoResults:String!
    }
```

Comment: Wow, that actually looks pretty good. That's basically what i'm trying to do. I'll try that later. Thanks.